# Which of these two possible meanings of this sentence is correct?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, songs

I have a question regarding this quote from "Ravens" by "Mount Eerie":

> And in every dream I have at night
>   And in every room I walk into like here
>   Where I sit the next October
>   Still seeing your eyes
>   **Pleading and afraid, full of love**
>   Calling out from another place
>   Because you're not here
>   I watched you die in this room
>   Then I gave your clothes away
>   I'm sorry, I had to
>   Now I'll move

The writer of this song is addressing his dead wife.
Originally I thought that "Pleading and afraid, full of love" is referring to his wife's eyes (mentioned in the preceding sentence).
Then I wasn't so sure. I started to think he might be referring to himself  - i.e. he's the one who is "pleading and afraid, full of love", when he is thinking about his wife, since she is not actually there.

Based on the phrasing of this sentence and the context in which it appears, are both meanings equally valid, or can we determine which one is correct?

Comment: Half the point of poetry is multiple valid meanings… yet how is the Question not literary criticism?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's literary criticism.

Answer (score 0):

When interpreting poetry or other literature, there's no such thing as a "correct" interpretation. Some interpretations might be easier to argue a case for than others, but it's really up to the reader to decide.

You might try to research what the author thought it meant; sometimes that information is available in notes, letters, or interviews. Whether the author's interpretation is definitive is of course a matter of opinion. There's a school of thought called [death of the author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_the_Author) that argues the author isn't any more authoritative than any other reader.